# jQuery Hide Divs on toggle

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to hide and show two separate hidden divs which are triggered by two different buttons

JQUERY

```
 jQuery("#flip4").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
  });

 jQuery("#flip6").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel6").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

CSS

```
#panel4 {padding:30px 20px;background-color:#000;display:none;width:460px;height:175px;margin:8px 0 0 -475px;z-index: 10000;position:absolute;box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px #0D0D0D;border-radius:3px;color:#F1F1F1;}

#panel6 {padding:30px 20px;background-color:#000;display:none;width:420px;height:45px;margin: 0 0 0 418px;z-index: 10000;position:absolute;box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px #0D0D0D;border-radius:3px;color:#F1F1F1;top: 94px;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="flip4"><a id="vphone" href="#"></a></div>

<div id="flip6"><a id="vemail" href="#"></a></div>
```

The problem I have is that I don't want at anytime the two divs to be shown together. i.e. if the `flip4` is visible and the user clicks on `flip6`then jquery needs to hide `flip4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to handle this, depending on the exact functionality you're looking for, you should try one of these two:

```
 jQuery("#flip4").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
    jQuery("#panel6").slideUp("slow");
  });

 jQuery("#flip6").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
    jQuery("#panel6").slideUp("slow");
  });
```

OR:

```
 jQuery("#flip4").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        jQuery("#panel6").slideUp("slow");
    });
  });

 jQuery("#flip6").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel4").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        jQuery("#panel6").slideUp("slow");
    });
  });
```